# Plotly mpl_to_plotly error: 'Spine' object has no attribute 'is_frame_like'

Tags: matplotlib, plotly-python

I have a matplotlib figure that I want to convert to plotly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly

fig = plt.figure()

## Lots of code to create my figure ##

plotly_fig = mpl_to_plotly(fig)
```

The error I get is **AttributeError: 'Spine' object has no attribute 'is_frame_like'**

I thought the function was pretty straightforward, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs is because it calls a removed function in Matplotlib.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\matplotlylib\mpltools.py", line 368
    spine_frame_like = spine.is_frame_like()
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The is_frame_like function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
```

In the latest commit of plotly [packages/python/plotly/plotly/matplotlylib/mpltools.py line 368](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/b90126e2623400274737e9fa6767e69df67c4e50/packages/python/plotly/plotly/matplotlylib/mpltools.py#L368), it still calls `is_frame_like()` function. There is already an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1568) tracking this. You may need choose to downgrade Matplotlib if you still want to use `mpl_to_plotly()` function.

[nicolaskruchten](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten), a member of the Plotly organization, says in that issue

> Indeed, our matplotlib conversion utility should be considered **deprecated** at this point as it *isn’t being actively maintained* to track deprecations and changes in matplotlib itself so it works best with older versions of matplotlib. I should update the docstrings accordingly.

In the meantime, he claims

> That said, if someone wants to work on it to bring it back up to date I’d be happy to work with them to integrate the changes :)

Comment: Looking at the comments in that issue, it looks like Plotly is considering `mpl_to_plotly` to be deprecated.

Comment: @nedned Thank you, I have added that to my answer in case someone may not look at that issue carefully.