# Use iterative plt.plot in a Dash Dashboard

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib, plot, plotly-dash

I had to create a Gantt chart, but with specific features so I hand-made it.
The visual is great when executing in Spyder.
To make it usable, I would like to add it to a dashboard.
The thing is that to convert the plt.plot to a plotly, I saw that you need :
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig)

But the way I ploted the fig is through plots in for loops :

```
for i in range (ite):  
  X=(df.start_num[i],df.start_num[i]+df.days_start_to_end[i])  
  Y=((ite-i)*coeff,(ite-i)*coeff)  
  plt.plot(X,Y,color=df.iloc[i][4], marker='.',linewidth=2, markersize=0)
```

(What I do is plotting the duration of each event on one Y line)

I have other loops to plot other elements.
Is there a clean way to gather all of them so I can convert the figure to a mpl plot ?
I've been trying to create lists, populated with the X and Y values and have a
fig=plt.plot(Xlist, Ylist...) but it is plotting crap.

Thank you very much!
Here is the only way to share the chart :
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/801664iFA2B0C8A7059E224/image-size/medium?v=v2&px=400

Comment: Please try to add a figure to your question. Do you have multiple figures?

Comment: By the way, with the last version of Matplotlib, `mpl_to_plotly` does not work and through an error. Therefore, Plotly is not compatible with the last version of Matplotlib and I recommend converting your mpl to plotly manually to add it to a dashboard.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120058/plotly-mpl-to-plotly-error-spine-object-has-no-attribute-is-frame-like

Comment: Hello Hamzah.
No, just one plot, the idea would be to have one plot on the dashboard but to filter the input depending on user interaction with the dashboard.

Comment: Plotly supports Gantt chart. I encourage you to try it out rather than plotting it by matplotlib and then converting it to plotly.

Comment: Ok so the whole point was to be able to have different starting dates for one tasks, in the case where one task is paused and starts again later.
Of all I've seen this is not possible with any solution (powerbi, plotly librairy, dash librairy etc).
Do you know a way this could be achieved ? 
The image on my post is not showing the start and stop condition, since importing images on stackover flow seems to be a major issue I couldnt show you the actual plot.